# Unexpected error of the task "ResolvePackageAssets"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I just created a blank solution and then added a console project(.net core 3.1). 
[image]

The problem is that I get an error: (MSB4018) Unexpected error of the task "ResolvePackageAssets" and if I look below it shows me this error:

```
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package 
folder 'C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\'.
```

If I try to change the version I get shown a lot of errors (VS no longer recognizes namespaces and keywords). I use Visual Studio 2019 for windows, I still worked with .net standard and .net core(the version currently installed on the computer is the 3.1.101).
There are no NuGet packages installed and I have a similar error in another project where I use Monogame along with a .net standard library (if I change version of the .net standard library I get the same error)

Does anyone know how to solve it? Meanwhile thank you.

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT Ok, thank you. You have a good day too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution that worked for me, I simply added the Microsoft folder to C:\ and inside the Microsoft folder I added the following folders: Xamarin\NuGet then I started Visual Studio and built the project